# Function ambiguous in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

The following code gives error that request for member fcn1 is ambiguous. Why is this happening?

```
class Base1 {
public:
  void fcn1(int x) {}
};

class Base2 {
public:
  void fcn1(int x, int) {}
};

class D: public Base1, public Base2 {
};


int main()
{
  D* d = new D;
  d->fcn1(1);
}
```

Putting the following in class D makes it work

```
public:
  using Base1::fcn1;
  using Base2::fcn1;
```

Comment: Is it still ambigious if you fix `void fcn1(int x, int) {}` in `Base 2` to be `void fcn1(int x, int y) {}` ?

Comment: @StarPilot: but of course it will still be ambiguous

Comment: I like Clang's error: *error: member 'fcn1' found in multiple base classes of different types*